# find command to rename files

Tags: linux, shell, find, command

I have created a list of files with names in uppercase alphabets and trying to rename them to files with the same names but in lowercase alphabets. So if i have 20 files with filenames like FILE1, FILE2, FILE3, etc. I want to rename them to file1, file2, file3, etc. respectively. I am executing the below command

```
[root@host-1-1 files]# find . -name 'FILE*' -exec mv  {} `echo {} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` \;
```

But i am receiving below errors from mv command. Could someone please tell me what i am missing here?
mv: ‘./FILE1’ and ‘./FILE1’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE2’ and ‘./FILE2’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE3’ and ‘./FILE3’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE4’ and ‘./FILE4’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE5’ and ‘./FILE5’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE6’ and ‘./FILE6’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE7’ and ‘./FILE7’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE8’ and ‘./FILE8’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE9’ and ‘./FILE9’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE10’ and ‘./FILE10’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE11’ and ‘./FILE11’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE12’ and ‘./FILE12’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE13’ and ‘./FILE13’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE14’ and ‘./FILE14’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE16’ and ‘./FILE16’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE18’ and ‘./FILE18’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE20’ and ‘./FILE20’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE15’ and ‘./FILE15’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE17’ and ‘./FILE17’ are the same file
mv: ‘./FILE19’ and ‘./FILE19’ are the same file
[root@host-1-1 files]#

PS: I have already used for loop and have fulfilled my requirement. I am working on my understanding in find command.

Comment: It looks like you're running this as root; as you may know, you should use an account with lesser permissions whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the command substitution happens first:

```
`echo {} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
```

Leaving {} as the name to rename it to. Only then does `find -exec` replace the `{}` with the filenames, at which point this is the template it's filling in:

```
mv {} {}
```

Of course, that results in `mv ./FILE1 ./FILE1` which gives the error you're getting.

Comment: I would do it with a `for` loop in the shell, the way you say in the question that you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

YMMV, but I generally reach for the `rename` command, because it:

- is simple,
- has a *”dry-run”* option (`-n`)
- won’t clobber if two files rename to the same output file.

Your command then becomes:

```
rename -n 'y/A-Z/a-z/' FILE*
```

Link to some [examples](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm) and [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html).

Comment: Editing my previous like. I tried the rename option on my CentOS system. invalid option.. :(

Comment: I think it may be called `prename` on CentOS - as it’s a Perl script really.