# OSX / MacOs batch rename hexadecimal filenames to decimal filenames

Tags: bash, macos, file-rename

I want to rename filenames with a hexadecimal part in the name to decimal. For example: `MOV12B.MOD`, `MOV12C.MOD` etc. To `MOV299.mod`, `MOV300.MOD`.

Can this be done in terminal?

It is possible to rename the extension using:

```
find . -name "*.MOD" -exec rename 's/\.MOD$/.MPG/' '{}' \;
```

But how can I rename the files to decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do it with `rename`, also known as `Perl rename` and `prename` which is most simply installed on macOS with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install rename
```

Then the command is:

```
rename --dry-run 's/[0-9A-F]+/hex($&)/e' *MOD
```

**Sample Output**

```
'MOV10.MOD' would be renamed to 'MOV16.MOD'
'MOV12B.MOD' would be renamed to 'MOV299.MOD'
'MOV12C.MOD' would be renamed to 'MOV300.MOD'
'MOVBEEF.MOD' would be renamed to 'MOV48879.MOD'
```

If you like what it does, remove the `--dry-run` part and do it for real.

I would recommend you make a backup before trying this anyway, because if your films are actually named `"Film 23.MOD"` rather than `"MOV12B.MOD"` you will get:

```
'Film 23.MOD' would be renamed to '15ilm 23.MOD'
```

---

If you want to put the date in too, you can do:

```
rename --dry-run 's/[0-9A-F]+/hex($&)/e; s|.MOD| 17/01/2018.MOD|' *MOD
```

**Sample Output**

```
'MOV12A.MOD' would be renamed to 'MOV298 17/01/2018.MOD'
```

---

Why couldn't you find it in the man-page? Well, there is a line in there that casually says you can pass a line of Perl code to modify the name. That means that the *entire Perl language* is available to you - so you could write several pages of code that access a database, run something on a remote machine, or fetch a URL in order to rename your file.

The only tricky thing in my code is the `e` lurking at the end:

```
s/search/replace/e
```

The `e` means that the second half of the search/replace is actually **executed** so it is not a straight textual replacement, it is a new program that gets the search string from the left-hand side in `$&` and can do maths or lookups on it.

I have done some other answers that involve similar techniques...

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48281308/2836621),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47070048/2836621),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41679334/2836621).

---

If you want to put the modification time of the file into its name as well, you need to do a little more work. First, `stat()` the file before changing its name ;-) Remember you receive the original filename in `$_`. Then do the the hex to decimal thing, then add in the `mtime`. Remember Perl uses a dot to concatenate strings together.

So, the command is going to look like this:

```
rename --dry-run 'my $mtime=(stat($_))[9]; s/[0-9A-F]+/hex($&) . " " . $mtime/e;' *MOD
```

**Sample Output**

```
'MOV12A.MOD' would be renamed to 'MOV298 1516229449.MOD'
```

If all the substitution and evaluation gets too much, you can always do all your calculations and assign the result to Perl's `$_` variable through which you receive the into filename and in which you pass the desired name back to `rename`. So, for an example:

```
rename --dry-run 'my $prefix="PREFIX "; my $middle=$_; my $suffix=" SUFFIX"; $_=$prefix . $middle . $suffix;' *MOD 
'MOV12A.MOD' would be renamed to 'PREFIX MOV12A.MOD SUFFIX'
```

---

Only a real programmer would store his movies with hex names - kudos to you!

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, it's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: PS. I read the help but I could not figure out how you find this solution. I also want to add the modified date to the filename but don't know how ....

Comment: It's late here - I will explain it more tomorrow.

Comment: Hello Hans, I have updated the answer with some additional material. Glad to be of help.

Comment: Maybe also note that if you have a file with no hex in the base name like `whut.MOD`, it will be renamed to `whut.MO13`

Comment: @tripleee Thank you, that is true too. The hex part is not that well defined or delimited in the question, which is why I suggested the backup and dry-run. I hope OP will check carefully before running. If there are edge cases, I guess the replacement could be tightened up but I would need to see quite a few filenames to be sure I had got them all! Anyway, yes, thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your great input. Your solution has a fixed date, I would like to have the modified date from the renamed file. I want to try the STAT(filename)[9] perl command but I get an error when using this command with /e.  I was able to prevent the rename in the extension, I renamed all the files after the proces ;)

Comment: I have added the `mtime` aspect into my answer - I hope I understood it correctly.

Comment: How to do it vice-versa? Rename files (without consider what's their name) to hex base 16, recursively? So, when it goes to the next folder, it remembers what was the previous naming and continue from there? For example: F1: 1.jpg, 1_A.jpg | F2: 1.jpg;;; will become-> F1: 1.jpg, 2.jpg | F2: 3.jpg

Comment: @Dr.jacky Please just ask a new question - they are free, and answers. You'll reach a better audience than by tagging a question onto a 4 year old answer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell totally right; Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70471333/how-to-rename-files-recursively-to-hex-base-16