# How to rename files recursively to hex base 16

Tags: javascript, python, bash, macos

How to rename files in different folders (but all folders are under one folder)(without considering what's their names) to hex base 16, recursively?

[image: example of folders hierarchy]

So, when it goes to the next folder, it remembers what was the previous naming it did and it continues from there.

---

For example(different than the screenshot):
Folder1: 1.jpg, 1_A.jpg, ... 10th_blah.jpg
Folder2: **1.jpg**, ..., 2000th_text1.jpg

will become ->
FolderAllTogether: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ..., A.jpg, **B.jpg**, ..., 7D0.jpg

---

The solution could be in javascript, bash, python, or any other script languages I can run easily on macOS.

---

My code:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path');
const dir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ImagesSuperTemp');
let i = 0

function renameFilesRecursive(dir, from, to) {

    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(it => {
        const itsPath = path.resolve(dir, it);
        const itsStat = fs.statSync(itsPath);

        if (itsPath.search(from) > -1) {
            console.log(`${i} : rename ${from} to ${to}`);
            fs.renameSync(itsPath, itsPath.replace(from, to))
            i = i + 1
        }

        if (itsStat.isDirectory()) {
            renameFilesRecursive(itsPath.replace(from, to), from, to)
        }
    })
}

renameFilesRecursive(dir, /\*.jpg$/, `${i.toString(16)}.jpg`);
```

But it does nothing!

Comment: Basically you just get a full list of all files, create a counter (can be int), iterate over the files and increment that counter after renaming your files to the counters hex value

Comment: Do you have access to Perl's standalone `rename` or `prename`?

Comment: @Cyrus I can install it. Is this correct? https://learn.perl.org/installing/osx.html

Comment: You can also install Perl's standalone `rename` on **macOS** with **homebrew** using the command `brew install rename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is below a bash script.
Change the values of `dest_dir` and `source_dir`

Do not forget to make it executable with `chmod +x flattener.sh`

```
#!/bin/env bash

dest_dir="/var/tmp/flat-files"
source_dir="parent-dir"

if [ ! -d "${dest_dir}" ] ; then
  mkdir -p "${dest_dir}"
fi

if [ ! -f "${dest_dir}"/index.dat ] ; then 
  printf "1" > "${dest_dir}"/index.dat || exit 1
fi

find "${source_dir}" -type f -print0 |\
  xargs -0 bash -c ' \
    for filename ; do \
      index=$(cat '"${dest_dir}"'/index.dat) ;\
      printf "%d" $((index+1)) > '"${dest_dir}"'/index.dat ;\
      if [[ "${filename}" =~ [.] ]] ; then \
        extension=."${filename##*.}" ;\
      else \
        extension="" ;\
      fi ;\
      mv -vu "${filename}" '"${dest_dir}"'/$(printf "%X" $index)"${extension}" ;\
    done' flattener
```

Comment: tnQ. I see that you are renaming by moving the file `mv`. Is there a way to not touch/move the origin files but, having the new renamed ones in the destination folder?

Comment: to copy the files change `mv` with `cp`.

Comment: It worked! Just wanted to let you know the index.dat shows 145048 but, the first filename is 1 and the last filename is 23697, which is 145047.

Comment: index.dat contains the next unused index in decimal ready to use. So, I think this is OK.

Answer (score 1):

#### Python solution

(throws you an error if you want to rename a file which already exists, e.g. you are processing image 5.jpg while your counter is at 3, but 3.jpg exists already; Could avoid that with a `try` `except` clause but then you do not have pictures always incremented by 1 - not sure what you require):

```
import os
counter = 1
for r, d, f in os.walk(r"Images"):  # can also put a full path here
    for name in f:
        # first argument here is full path to the image
        # second argument is the path + the hex number of the counter + the extension of the file
        os.rename(r + os.sep + name, r + os.sep + hex(counter).lstrip("0x") + os.path.splitext(name)[-1])
        counter += 1
```

---

##### Edit

I further documentated the code, added a status-message and noticed that you want uppercase hex file names:

```
import os
counter = 1
for r, d, f in os.walk(r"Images"):  # can also put a full path here
    for name in f:
        # full path to original image
        original_fn = r + os.sep + name

        # path + hex number of counter + extension of file
        new_fn = r + os.sep + hex(counter).lstrip("0x").upper() + os.path.splitext(name)[-1]  

        # rename, status print, incrementing counter
        os.rename(original_fn, new_fn)
        print(f"Renamed {original_fn} > {new_fn}")
        counter += 1
```

---

##### Edit 2

Here is a solution to first rename all files to temporary files with random strings attached, and after that rename all of them to hex numbers based on a counter. Hope that solves your problems:

```
import os
import random
import string

for r, d, f in os.walk(r"Images"):
    for name in f:
        rnd_string = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(12))
        original_fn = r + os.sep + name
        new_fn = r + os.sep + rnd_string + name
        os.rename(original_fn, new_fn)
        print(f"Temp. rename {original_fn} > {new_fn}")

counter = 1
for r, d, f in os.walk(r"Images"):  # can also put a full path here
    for name in f:
        original_fn = r + os.sep + name
        new_fn = r + os.sep + hex(counter).lstrip("0x").upper() + os.path.splitext(name)[-1]  
        os.rename(original_fn, new_fn)
        print(f"Final rename {original_fn} > {new_fn}")
        counter += 1
```

Comment: It removes a batch of files if I run it again and again!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wYi0D0Lg

Comment: @Dr.jacky i dont see any indication of files being deleted, the code also does not allow that - what happens if the rename fails (due to a file already existing) is that it throws an Exception and the code stops. It also looks like you executed the code multiple times, which i dont fully understand. If you want to do a dry-run, simply comment the line containing `os.rename(original_fn, new_fn)`.

Comment: But, not only on the terminal, in the folders, I lose the files after I run it command again and again. I could take a screenshot if you want. But anyway, is there any solution to not care if they are already renamed? If they are, let's do it again - apart from running the command again and again, there is a chance that in other folders, there is a file that has the hex base 16 name.

Comment: @Dr.jacky i edited my answer to provide a solution to first rename all files to temporary names and then rename the temporary names to hex values based on your counter - hope that fixes your problem. Also i would be surprised if the total amount of files was reduced by the previous code.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` >= 4.0 and `cp` (no `mv`/`rename`):

```
shopt -s globstar
unset int
for i in **/*.jpg; do
  ((int++))
  printf -v hex '%x' "$int"
  echo cp -v "$i" "FolderAllTogether/${hex^^}.jpg"
done
```

If output looks okay, remove `echo`.

Comment: `line 1: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name`
`line 6: FolderAllTogether/${hex^^}.jpg: bad substitution`

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need bash version >= 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` and `find`:

```
#!/bin/bash

srcdir='/path/to/source/directory'
dstdir='/path/to/destination/directory'

n=1
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    while [[ -e $dstdir/$(printf '%X' $n).jpg ]]; do ((++n)); done
    cp -- "$file" "$dstdir/$(printf '%X' $n).jpg"
done  < <(find "$srcdir" -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0)
```

If source and destination directories are on the same filesystem, you may consider replacing the `cp` with `ln`.

Comment: `batch-renamer-hex3.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `<'`
`batch-renamer-hex3.sh: line 10: `done  < <(find "$srcdir" -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0)'`

Comment: @Dr.jacky How do you run the script?

Comment: Put th code inside a fileExample.sh and then run it like: `sh fileExample.sh`

Comment: @Dr.jacky That's not a correct way to run a _bash script_. You should run it as either  `bash fileExample.sh`, or `chmod +x fileExample.sh` and then `./fileExample.sh` You are running it as a standard shell script.

Comment: @Dr.jacky btw, I've edited the script not to overwrite the existing files, though it may still invoke race condition when two instance of the script is run at the same time, for example.

Comment: @Dr.jacky And, naming a bash script with `.sh` extension is usually misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I am only adding this for completeness in response to your actual question which asked to **rename** files, although it transpires you actually want to **copy** files.

You can do it with Perl `rename` like this:

```
find images -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | rename --stdin -n -0 -N 01 '$_=sprintf("%X.jpg", $N);'
```

**Sample Output**

```
'images/11/5.jpg' would be renamed to '1.jpg'
'images/11/3.jpg' would be renamed to '2.jpg'
'images/6/2.jpg' would be renamed to '3.jpg'
'images/6/3.jpg' would be renamed to '4.jpg'
'images/1/17.jpg' would be renamed to '5.jpg'
'images/1/21.jpg' would be renamed to '6.jpg'
'images/1/22.jpg' would be renamed to '7.jpg'
'images/1/23.jpg' would be renamed to '8.jpg'
'images/1/1_A.jpg' would be renamed to '9.jpg'
'images/1/25.jpg' would be renamed to 'A.jpg'
'images/1/1.jpg' would be renamed to 'B.jpg'
```

The key to preserving a counter across directories is to use `-N 01` and then you have an auto-incrementing counter you can dink with.

---

If you have bash 4 or newer or `zsh` (I think), you can probably get away with this simpler version:

```
rename -n -N 01 '$_=sprintf("%X.jpg", $N)' images/**/*.jpg
```

---

Note that Perl `rename` is most simply installed on **macOS** with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install rename
```